# How to create array with loop for

Tags: typescript

I have no idea to create array by json data

my code

```
for (let y of x.FACET){
    console.log(y["@KEY"])
    var numericArray: number[] = [y["@KEY"]];
    console.log(numericArray)
}
```

output

```
console.log(y["@KEY"]) show  
    1221 
    1334 
    1456 
    1876

console.log(numericArray) show
    ["1221"]
    ["1334"]
    ["1456"]
    ["1876"]
```

> I want create [1221, 1334, 1456, 1876]; for sort number...

my listpage

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of  totalfilter">
          <p>{{item["@KEY"]}}</p>
        </ion-item>

        </ion-list>
```

Comment: before loop: `var results = [];` in loop: `results.push(y["@KEY"]);`

Comment: thanks for your help But I get error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry, wasn't paying enough attention, my suggestion is javascript only. The posted answer is the same logic I was going for

Comment: Ahh , I'm sorry it's my mistake. your code is correct! thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialise the array first, and after that push the values in there

```
let numericArray: number[] = [];

for (let y of x.FACET){
    numericArray.push(y["@KEY"]));       
}
```

One line solution:

```
let numericArray: number[] = x.FACET.map(v => parseInt(v["@KEY"]));
```

To sort the `x.FACET` array you can do this:

```
x.FACET.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    return parseInt(a["@KEY"]) - parseInt(b["@KEY"]);
});
```

Comment: I have one question , Can sort number by `y["@KEY"]` without create array? because I create array to sort number but list is not show by sort /// I editted post. please help me T-T